# Placement student savings account

Tags: united-kingdom, savings, student, university

I have started a placement year (full time job for 14 months) as part of my university degree. I am looking to save a regular amount of money each month - something that would gain interest (if possible). What type of account should I look into opening & would it be worth opening a current account with the same bank? Also, how should I work out how much money to save per month?
TIA

Comment: "something that would gain interest" - check interest rates. Seriously with the amount of money you save it is just one thing: NOT WORTH IT. You talk of a slice of pizza in a year. We live in a time where banks start offering NEGATIVE interest rates. Not against saving - but forget "earning interest rate" - you will be disappointed.

Comment: @TomTom I'm not sure where you live, but in the UK then there are still savings accounts offering 5% interest (see the link in my answer).

Comment: @TomTom ok - what do you mean by 'You talk of a slice of pizza in a year' ?

Comment: 500 USD per month saving, 12 months is 6000 USD. At 1% that would be 60 USD. Math. Ok, maybe a cehap evening, but it is not a lot.

Comment: Yes it is not a lot, but you may as well look for the best offer available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to look for a Regular Savings account. Most major banks offer these and they are specifically designed for your scenario of saving a regular amount of money each month.

You'll get a higher interest rate than a standard savings account, but you will be committed to paying in a minimum amount each month and there may also be restrictions on withdrawals. You'll also often find there's a maximum you can pay in each month.

Often then the highest interest rates are only available if you also have a current account at the same bank.

MoneySavingExpert have a writeup with some of the top performing accounts [here](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/best-regular-savings-accounts/).